# automatically update database when content of variable changes

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say you have a class:

```
class someClass {

private $name;

}
```

In this class you have some methods. In those methods you change the variable `$name`.

My question ist the following:

Is it possible, that every time you call a certain method of this class, the variable `$name` gets a value from  a database? And when the method is over, the value of `$name`, which might be changed somewhere in the method gets inserted back in the database?

So an example:

You have a database table with a row

```
`name`='Alfred'
```

When you now call a method inside the `someClass`-class, the variable `$name` automatically fetches the name in the database-table. So `$name` is now 'Alfred'

In the method you have called, `$name` changes to 'Bob'.

Now, when the method is over, the new value of the `$name` variable automatically inserts into the database table. Now you find:

```
`name`='Bob'
```

in the database table

Is this possible? Is it anyway useful? It just came to my mind, while I was thinking about a problem.

Comment: just store the original in a var at the top of the method and if they differ at the end update the database

Comment: use javascript to trigger an onchange event

Comment: Initially, you have define your variable as global. Then fetch value from the table, store in $name at beginning of the class. Then change the value of your variable and use update command at end of the class.

Comment: Post your code snippet, That is better to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an abstraction of the table you want to modify. You don't have to change or read the value of variable directly, but throgh a setter and a getter method.
I explain. You have to create a class "table" that has a private variable "user" and two public methods: getUser and setUser. In the "set" method you change the value of variable and the value in the database. In the "get" method you can read from the database or, if you are sure that every change in the user variable is made by the "set" method, you can return simply the user variable.
In the class "someClass" you have to create a "Table" object and use these methods to read and write database.
I hope it could be helpful.